# error: A 'name' attribute is required for <item> (styles.xml)

Tags: android

I try to import a project to eclipse but I found a problem in res/values/styles.xml.that's what I received in the console:

```
[2015-12-12 13:01:04 - AllInOne]   D:\tpandroid\AllInOne\res\values\styles.xml:13: error: A 'name' attribute is required for <item>
[2015-12-12 13:01:04 - AllInOne] 
[2015-12-12 13:01:04 - AllInOne] D:\tpandroid\AllInOne\res\values\styles.xml:19: error: A 'name' attribute is required for <item>
[2015-12-12 13:01:04 - AllInOne] 
[2015-12-12 13:01:04 - AllInOne] D:\tpandroid\AllInOne\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-12-12 13:01:04 - AllInOne] 
[2015-12-12 13:01:04 - AllInOne] D:\tpandroid\AllInOne\res\values\styles.xml:13: error: Error: Resource id cannot be an empty string: attr ''.
[2015-12-12 13:01:04 - AllInOne] 
[2015-12-12 13:01:04 - AllInOne] D:\tpandroid\AllInOne\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-12-12 13:01:04 - AllInOne] 
[2015-12-12 13:01:04 - AllInOne] D:\tpandroid\AllInOne\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-12-12 13:01:04 - AllInOne] 
[2015-12-12 13:01:04 - AllInOne]      D:\tpandroid\AllInOne\res\values\styles.xml:19: error: Error: Resource id cannot be an empty string: attr ''.
[2015-12-12 13:01:04 - AllInOne]
```

that's styles.xml:

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
    <item />
 </style>

 <!-- Application theme. -->
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level    can go here. -->
    <item />
</style>


</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the error means that `<item />` is not allowed. It needs to be `<item name="..." />`.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you tried to declare an item without `name`tag in the styles file. for example, you may have simply opened a item tag and closed it like below:

```
<item>
</item>
```

To fix this, add the "name" into the item tag, for instance it should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

See mandatory `name` attributes above. Check [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Comment: good first answer @camelon, I just reworded it alittle to be clearer. welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Actually in my case the error was showing for file values.xml which is a build file so  can't change it. The actual error was on style.xml file where